# Why does jQuery tie their ajax request object to a window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why does JQuery ( [latest source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) ) tie there Ajax Request Object to a window like this?

```
    return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
```

I'm asking b.c. in my source I don't do this.

I just do

```
return new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Because that's usually where the xmlhttprequest method lives. It's just made into a global object for `new XML...` purposes for backwards compatibility.

Comment: as in when xmlhttprequest is defined, it's done as a child object of the window object.

Comment: Yes, but if you're seventeen nested scopes deep (which happens in jquery) the look up becomes expensive time-wise as the browser has to asks each enclosing parent scope if the reference is defined in that scope. see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `XMLHttpRequest` object is a child of the `window` object.

You can reference it as a lone object since `window` is the parent scope in the browser; i.e. the global scope. If the reference isn't in the local scope (closure), JavaScript keeps going up the scope chain until the reference found. Using `window.XMLHttpObject` prevents all the look ups by telling the browser exactly where to find it.

Comment: window is passed in to jQuery..so they are taking advantage of this optimization as well.

Comment: To summarize: the second line of the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states: "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: @GuyMontag I'm in the midst of working on stuff using Backbone (so we're adding that in), but I'm 10 levels deep in my call stack in a function which runs on a successful `.fetch`.  The first FIVE of those are jQuery by itself.  Then the backbone stuff kicks in.

Comment: @GuyMontag So yes, 17 was made up, but not that large of an exaggeration.  Imagine having to pay the cost of walking up that scope chain each time?  Scoping is your best JavaScript friend.